# Why is bias "constant" in bias variance tradeoff derivation?

Tags: regression, variance, bias, unbiased-estimator, mse

I know there are plenty of questions about the Bias/Variance tradeoff.  I've been trying to derive it myself to build some intuition.

I looked at the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) page, and I saw this: [image: bias/variance derivation from wikipedia]

Notice where it says "This is a constant...".  Which part of the expression `E[theta-hat] - theta` is constant?

Let's use linear regression as an example, fitting `y=mx+b`.  After fitting a line, the expected value of `y` at a given value `x` is constant, sure, because it is just plugging in `x` into our linear model.  But are we talking about the expected value of our model at a particular `x`, or the expected value of all of the `y`'s predicted by our model (i.e. the sample mean of the y's, `y-bar`)?

If it is the latter, then this doesn't seem like a constant value to me.  The difference between the true model, and the model estimate will vary depending on `x`.  In linear regression, if the difference didn't vary, then the true linear relationship, and our estimate must be parallel.

What are we calling "constant", e.g. in linear regression?  I chose linear regression for its ease of illustrating these concepts.

Comment: The key is that although $\theta$ may be unknown, it is constant. And of course, $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta})$ is constant.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/mse-decomposition-to-variance-an-bias-square

Comment: It might help a bit for me to get an example of $\theta$.  In linear regression, is  $\theta$ the true model, `y=mx+b` from which the values were generated? If so, then I don't understand what we mean by "constant", unless the slope is zero

Comment: If m were the true value of the parameter used to generate errored data, then $\theta$ would be m. Or it could be a vector of the combination of m and b.

Comment: OK, thank you.  Let's stick with `m` being our parameter of interest for a bit.  So, then why would our estimate of `m` ever vary?  I understand that the expected value of anything is a constant of course.  But, in this case it actually seems like there is only one value for `m` in our model.

Comment: m is fixed, i.e., constant, but we don't know what it is, that's why we estimate it. Given a particular estimation procedure (presuming it's not a randomized algorithm), if we repeat the same procedure with the same data, we get the same estimate.  But if we repeat it with different data, we can get a different estimate.  If we knew m exactly, we could use the estimate of m being m, which has zero variance and zero bias, therefore zero mean square error.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand, thanks so much for your patience @MarkL.Stone.  So, the expected value of our estimates of `m` would be the average of all of estimates during our estimation procedure?  And, since ordinary least squares is just a convex optimization problem, there is only one minimum, so there **is** only one estimate in this case?