# How is the true label 'constant' in the derivation of the bias-variance decomposition

Tags: probability, variance, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff

In the derivation of the bias variance decomposition for example [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/mse-decomposition-to-variance-and-bias-squared) the following identity is used:

$$E[(E[\hat{f}]-\hat{f})(f-E[\hat{f}])]=E[E[\hat{f}]-\hat{f}](f-E[\hat{f}])$$

with the justification that '$(f-E[\hat{f}])$ is constant'.

I do not understand this.

The expectation $E$ is taken over the distribution $P_X$ of the sample-generating random variable $X$, and both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are functions of the random variable $X$, hence random variables themselves.

Obviously $E[\hat{f}]$ is constant since it is an expected value, but $f$ is a function of the data: It maps a sample $x$ to its true label $f(x)$, and different samples $x$ have different labels, there is nothing constant about this.

I've read all answers on the bias-variance tradeoff and none explained how $f$ can be 'constant' when it takes different values for different samples.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've read it,f is the true function in the population, and therefore fixed since the population is assumed fixed (unlike the sample)